# Getting DisconnectableInputStream source reader while trying to run Gradle Build

Tags: gradle, nohup

I have a script that runs a `gradle build` like this...

```
$HOME_DIR$CODE_DIR/gradlew -p $HOME_DIR$CODE_DIR build
```

When I run this regularly like `./start.local.sh` it works fine. But when I try to use nohup like `nohup ./start.local.sh &` I get...

```
Exception in thread "DisconnectableInputStream source reader" org.gradle.api.UncheckedIOException: java.io.IOException: Bad file descriptor
    at org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException.throwAsUncheckedException(UncheckedException.java:57)
    at org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException.throwAsUncheckedException(UncheckedException.java:40)
    at org.gradle.util.DisconnectableInputStream$1.run(DisconnectableInputStream.java:125)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Bad file descriptor
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to define an input stream descriptor, this magic works for me:

```
nohup ./start.local.sh > build.log 2>&1 < /dev/null &
```

This is a known Gradle bug described in https://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-3535. 
Gradle expect for input (stdin) and output streams(stdout and stderr). When you use nohup command there is no stdin and stdout/err and you should define them if application have a tight requirements:

```
 2>&1 - redirect for stderr to stdout, 
 > build.log - redirect stdout to log file, 
 < /dev/null - use /dev/null as input stream
```

Comment: Please add explanation as well.

Comment: this answer is correct, so if you say want to compile and run a java project with all the output going to output.txt you would execute this command:
```nohup ./gradlew run > output.txt 2>&1 < /dev/null &```

Answer (score 0):

In my case on react native project, i only clean android project and build again.

```
cd android && ./gradlew clean
```

to re-run

```
cd .. && react-native run-android
```